# Why can't my code scrape all of the prices from the 1st page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I have a code that scrapes the prices from this Zillow page:
[Zillow page link](https://www.zillow.com/san-francisco-ca/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-122.5977810991211%2C%22east%22%3A-122.2688779008789%2C%22south%22%3A37.551346042275206%2C%22north%22%3A37.9985615568244%7D%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A11%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A20330%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Afalse%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22sort%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22days%22%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D).

When I run the code it gives me the first 9 prices of the apartments. I presume that the page loads in 2, 3 times so the code doesn't probably catch all of the prices.

What should I add/change to the code so that it chaces all of the prices from the first page?

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://www.zillow.com/san-francisco-ca/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-122.52499667529297%2C%22east%22%3A-122.34166232470703%2C%22south%22%3A37.662044543503555%2C%22north%22%3A37.88836615784793%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A20330%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22sort%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22days%22%7D%2C%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A12%7D"

header = {
  "User-Agent": "YOUR USER AGENT",
  "Accept-Language": "YOUR ACCEPT LANGUAGE"
}

response = requests.get(URL, headers=header)
web_page = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, 'html.parser')

# Prices
prices_dirty = soup.find_all("span", class_="PropertyCardWrapper__StyledPriceLine-srp__sc-16e8gqd-1 iMKTKr")
prices_list_clean = [price.getText().split()[0] for price in prices_dirty if price.getText().startswith('$')]
print(prices_list_clean)
```

Tried to Google the solution but didn't came across it.

Answer (score -1):

The website might rely on javascript to load the elements you're trying to get, which means that using requests and Beautifulsoup may not be sufficient to get the elements you want to retrieve.

When going to the `url`, you can inspect the page and see that only the first 9 prices can be found while looking for the class specified (`prices_dirty`) [as seen on my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEaLZ.png)

The next prices are loaded when scrolling the page.

You could look into the Selenium package (or similar) for these cases.